# Oppacity animation doesn't work in jQuery and in CSS

Tags: jquery, css, animation, opacity

I have a image which I'm trying to apply opacity to.

here's is the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#red').animate({
        opacity: 10
    }, 1500);

});
```

Nothing happens. I have also tried setting the opacity on the image through CSS . doesn't work that either...

**[Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nilzone/Nj2WA/1/)**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The opacity range goes from `0` to `1`: http://jsfiddle.net/Nj2WA/2/

More info [here](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/opacity)

Comment: @Nilzone- No worries. Happens to all of us